# how to remove ' \' from a list in Python

Tags: python

When I have two items that start with '\' in a list. I cant remove the second one. In this case '\x80'. I have tried everything but unsuccessfully.

```
s = ['a', 'b' , 'c' , '\xe2 ','\x80', 'd', 'f', 'g']

if x == '\x2' or x == '\80' :
    s.remove(x)

print s
```

I get: `['a', 'b', 'c','\x80', 'd', 'f','g']`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: They are just Unicode characters. Are you sure you want to remove them

Comment: Is that a typo? '\80' versus '\x80', and '\xe2' versus '\x2'?

Comment: You mean `x == '\x80'`?

Comment: Are you sure you are showing us the actual code? Because it doesn’t make much sense, e.g. `x` is undefined.

Comment: This is the actual code. Yes I need to remove this item,  and it is not undefined.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 s = ['a','k','c', '\xe2','f','g', '\x80' , '\x9c']

for x in s :
    if x == '\xe2'  or x == '\x80'  or x == '\x9c':
    s.remove(x)
  
print s

Comment: I get : ['a','k','c','f','g','\x9c']

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simply fix. Remove all characters with ascii values greater than 125 (}):

```
s = ['a', 'b' , 'c' , '\xe2','\x80', 'd', 'f', 'g']

s = [i for i in s if ord(i) < 126]   # keep only characters with ascii value less that 126
```

## [DEMO](http://repl.it/oVC/1)

Comment: what if the text also contained a '}' ?

Comment: The text does not contain '}'

Comment: I used  s = [i for i in s if ord(i) < 126]  and  problem solved.  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: sshashank124, How can I accept your answer? Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: @Avda7, Just click the green tick (should be hollow) under the upvote and downvote button just to the left of my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = ['a', 'b' , 'c' , '\xe2 ','\x80', 'd', 'f', 'g']
print [i for i in s if  re.match(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+",i)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string library (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html) page):

```
import string

s = ['a', 'b' , 'c' , '\xe2 ','\x80', 'd', 'f', 'g']
cleaned = [x for x in s if x in string.printable]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = ['a', 'b' , 'c' , '\xe2 ','\x80', 'd', 'f', 'g']
clean_list = []

for i in s:
   if '/' not in i:
      clean_list.append(i)
```